# I need Google Sheets App Script To Place Google Form Response Edit Link In Col 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have connected my Google form to my spreadsheet.  I have a blank (column 1) that I would like to be filled with the edit url that will take me back to the form so that I can edit the response from the form.

- To get the blank column I inserted a column infront of the timestamp column and added a the header in that blank column.  The header matches.

I used to use a code similar to this.  But I can't get this one to work.  It runs without error but does nothing.  Column 1 Does have matching Header "Edit Url"

```
// Form URL
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/form-id/viewform';
// Sheet name used as destination of the form responses
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
/*
* Name of the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs
* It should match exactly the header of the related column,
* otherwise it will do nothing.
*/
var columnName = 'Edit Url' ;
// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
var timestamp = data[i][0];
var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
}
}
}
```

What am I missing"  The form is setup to allow responses to be edited immediately after user hits submit

I tried adjusting the above code so that sheet name and form url were correct.  I haven't had success in the past with fanatical, solution. I just need to run the simpler app script coding.

- Problem Solved... here is the fix

1. Edit Url column needed to be the last column
2. The Form Link ... needed to be the "/edit" url and not the "/viewform" Link

Comment: `Problem Solved... here is the fix` Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved... here is the fix
Edit Url column needed to be the last column
The Form Link ... needed to be the "/edit" url and not the "/viewform" Link

Comment: You might find that the "Edit Url" column does not need to be the literal "last" column, so long as it is any column after the form responses.